# Server Fans Never Slow Down After Speeding Up

Tags: linux, fan, cooling

I have a server motherboard in a large tower case with several hard disks installed. It's basically a media server that serves over CIFS.

I'm using the 'sensors' command on Linux to monitor the system temperatures. It typically runs around 70c, but if it gets a tough load (downloading several things, hashing the downloaded content) it can cause the fans to spin up to max. An first this would happen briefly, then the fans would spin down after the system cooled. Now, however, the fans never spin down and just howl at full speed forever until the system is shut down for a moment then booted again. Rebooting vs hard cycling the system, curiously, often results in the fans never leaving the "bad state" and they stay on full power.

Troubleshooting steps I've tried:

- Alter BIOS temp control settings
- clean and reapply thermal paste
- double-check fan header connections
- clean dust off internal components

I'm using:

- CentOs 6.8
- Tyan S8230 motherboard
- (2) 12-core Opteron CPUs
- (2) Small Noctua case fans
- (2) Generic, medium case fans that came with the case.
- (2) std CPU coolers that came with the CPUs

ipmiutil sel list output:
http://sprunge.us/bJg0gM

Comment: Could you try to see if there is a firmware update for your motherboard? If you have the server under warranty you can contact the manufacturer. Check also the BMC log: `ipmitool sel list`, add the output to your question.

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of blockage / dust - so you actually have a hotspot near the fans or sensors??

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici added to question

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I interpret from `ipmitool sel list`:

```
038d 04/09/21 09:32:42 MAJ BMC  Fan #55  Lo Crit thresh act=08 thr=09
```

I think that you have a broken fan that runs slow and that makes other fans to spin up to compensate.
Check if you can see all the fans spinning at same speed.

Comment: Will do, but why doesn't it ever slow down, even when all the sensor readings plunge after the fans go up to 100%?

Comment: It could be a firmware bug. Have you updated UEFI/BIOS firmware of your motherboard to the latest version?

Comment: I checked out the fans when it was in the "bad  state" again last night. All the fans appear to be spinning at max RPM, and a majority of the noise is coming from the two CPU cooler fans. I have already tried removing any obvious dust or blockages. I'll double check that the bios is on the latest.